# Away3DLite on Android Objects doesn't appear on the screen

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5, away3d

I have implemented an Augmented Reality application on Adobe Air for Android. When I publish my app on the android mobile phone (Nexus One) the 3D models that I have created don't appear on the screen. On flash CS5 it is working fine.

I have used Away3DLite engine and I have imported a 3D collada object. I have also tried to publish some projects that I found online and I checked if the the 3D model appears on the screen but it doesn't show it either.

Does anyone know how the 3D Models that I have imported in my project using Away3DLite can be 
visible when I publish the application on the android phone?

Some extra stuff be usefull:

- I'm using GPU rendering

A also using a combination of the following softwares in order to create my AR application:

- FLARToolkit
- FLARManager
- Away3DLite

I have created one 3D Model on 3DS MAX and another one on Maya 2010.

I will really appreciate any advice i can get from you.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried debugging your app to see if there is any error?

Comment: @Florian F yes I have debbug my app and I don't have any error. I have tried download an application from away3D applications and i can't even use that one on my phone. The 3D models doesn't appear on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple primitive such as a Sphere, Cube, ...

Comment: @Florian F Yes, on the Android phone is working only with a simple primitives.

Comment: Ok. Do you load your 3D model locally or from a server? I wouldn't be surprised if it were a crossdomain issue...

Comment: I'm downloading my 3D model from a folden on my hard disk. I'm just loading the model using the path of the folder that is saved. for example  [Embed(source="../model.dae",mimeType="application/octet-stream")]. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Florian F I'm downloading my 3D model from a folden on my hard disk. I'm just loading the model using the path of the folder that is saved. for example [Embed(source="../model.dae",mimeType="application/octet-stream")]. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. What's the size file of your DAE?

Comment: @Florian F The size is 5,34KB because I just did a small cube and I have added a texture to check if the problem is the size. The main dae file that I'm going to use is 180KB. But I don't think that is my problem now cs is not working even with the small one.

Comment: Hmm... Do you know if it's loaded or not? I think you can add event listeners on progress and parsing. Another thing, have you tried to reduce the size of your stage in CS5 so it matches the size of your android screen?

Comment: @Florian F It is loaded because when I debbug it on Flash is working fine and shows the model. The size of my stage is 640 x 480 and it matches to the size of the android screen. Because on the left top corner of my stage where it show the framerates on the mobile is show it exactly to the same position.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you more then ... no more ideas :(

Comment: @Florian F thank you very much for your interest anyway.. :)

Comment: just a note: if you are using [Embed] you aren't really *loading* the model. it's embedded into your swf at compile time, so there's no point in listening for load progress.

Comment: @grapefrukt Thank you for your reply. What is the best method to load the model correctly? Because I think the problem that I have is when I publish the app on the mobile phone it cannot find the file.

Comment: again. the model is compiled into your swf, which is the sane thing to do with a model as small as yours. something else is making it not show up. add debug statements that trace out to a textfield so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is GPU rendering.

More specifically you use some feature, that is not available when you use GPU rendering. For limitations see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS901d38e593cd1bac-3d719af412b2b394529-8000.html . the important part is "If The GPU cannot render an object, it is not displayed at all."
GPU rendering+putting something over a video = problems in Air
Plus GPU rendering and the Camera class dont work together either: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d49zephyr_serranozephyr.html

"The Camera class is not supported in mobile AIR apps that use the GPU rendering mode."